# How to replace letters with another letters to create a encryption code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

I've been told in a project to create an encryption code using python, by replacing all the letters in alphabets with other random letters using a dictionary (ASCII). And let the user type something, then show him the encrypted message.

I did this but apparently it didn't work out:

```
string = input("Write a sentence to encrypt: ")

print(string.replace("a", "j"))
print(string.replace("b", "f"))
print(string.replace("c", "n"))
print(string.replace("d", "t"))

print(string.replace)
```

When I tried this code and added more and more letters, it didn't work (example: I typed "abc" to test it and instead of giving me "jfn" in output, it gives me "jyn").

```
string = input("Write a sentence to encrypt: ")

string = string.replace("a", "j")
string = string.replace("b", "f")
string = string.replace("c", "n")
string = string.replace("d", "t")
string = string.replace("e", "g")
string = string.replace("f", "y")
string = string.replace("g", "i")

print(string)
```

Output:

```
Write a sentence to encrypt: abc
jyn

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: What is your required output? Because you are not storing the strings with the replaced text just printing them

Comment: The built-in *replace* function for strings does not modify the string *in situ*. This is because Python strings are inherently immutable. Look at the return value. Also, if you're going to encode using random characters you'll never be able to decode it and that might be the next question in your class

Comment: After your edit... You have replaced b with f. You subsequently replace f with y. You seem surprised

Comment: You replace `b` with `f`, and then replace that `f` with `y`. As Arthur pointed out, why are you surprised?

Answer (score 1):

You should take care of not replacing characters that have already been replaced.

Something like the following could work for you.

```py
mapping = dict(zip('abc', 'xyz'))
string = 'abacabcd'

''.join(map(lambda char: mapping.get(char, char), string))
```